# How to set custom realm in embedded tomcat server? I am using Spring Boot.

Tags: tomcat7, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

How to set custom realm for the embedded tomcat? i am using SpringBoot however dont see a way to add custom realm via Embeddedservletcontainercustomizer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you should define this bean:

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.addContextCustomizers(new TomcatContextCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Context context) {
            context.setRealm(new CombinedRealm());
        }
    });
    return factory;
}
```

And provide the desired `Realm` implementation.

Comment: thanks very much for this, this resolved the issue, I see valve getting initialized in the logs. however my requests are bypassing the valve completely. any idea why would not go through the valve first ? do we need to do additional config from web.xml related to <security-constrain>/<security-role> ?

Comment: True. You can do it via `ServletContextInitializer` bean and provide `ServletContext.declareRoles`. I think...

Comment: How about adding in the customize() method above?

    SecurityConstraint sc = new SecurityConstraint();
    //add config here
    context.addConstraint( sc);
    context.addSecurityRole("all_auth_users");

Comment: Still not hitting the Valve, Ideally it should redirect the request to our centralized web authentication form, and once authenticated it would process the request. However looks like request directly hits dispatcher servlet and then controller even though I see in the logs 
2014-06-26 14:47:51.528  INFO 4048 --- [ost-startStop-1]       : GSAuthNAuthenticator (gsauthn-j version 4.1.1) started successfully.

Any other thoughts ?