# Spring boot embedded tomcat custom realm

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am aware of this question:  [embedded tomcat spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429315/how-to-set-custom-realm-in-embedded-tomcat-server-i-am-using-spring-boot)
however this leaves much to be desired as far as a solution is concerned,  Currently I have the following code which works to enable SSL:

```
TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers( (connector) -> {
     connector.setPort(8443);
     connector.setSecure(true);
     connector.setScheme("https");

     Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
     protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
     protocol.setKeystoreFile(keystore);
     protocol.setKeystorePass(password);
     protocol.setKeystoreType("jks");
     protocol.setKeyAlias(alias);
}
)
```

My question is this, if I have a Realm that looks like this in XML:

```
<Realm classname="foo.bar.baz | bing.bang.bong"
        var1 = "xyz"
        var2 = "123"
/>
```

How do I recreate that with embedded tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ContextCustomizer instead of the ConnectorCustomizer

```
tomcat.addContextCustomizers( (context) -> { 
    context.setRealm(...);
}
)
```

Comment: sure, but how do I actually build the realm?

Comment: Well not sure based on your question above what implementation of a realm you are using. But for instance look at the API for org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm and you will see it has a constructor and setters for the attributes you would normally configure in the XML.